# Flash Local Shared Object path

Tags: flash, object, actionscript, local, shared

(Before burning the last cd I have to make a test...)

I have a Flash.exe projector that stores data in a Shared Object. Anything works fine if I launch it from my desktop. The Flash.exe will be recorded and used from a CD-rom. Will the path of the Shared Object change? Say, will it try to record itself on the cd?!

Answer (score 0):

How can it write itself to the CD?? The CD is read-only.. It will create a file in the same place in which it would if it plays from a browser.

Comment: Being a cd a "disk" (in my case D:), I thought the Shared Object took as a base for its path the disk where it plays the exe.

Comment: No it doesn't, you can easily test it. The location is not based on the your file location, but on Flash Player location.

Comment: The fact is that when you pack the swf in the projector, then the player IS INSIDE the projector!

Comment: Even so, it will use a external location to write the share object, you shouldn't have a problem. Did you test this and it fails?

Comment: No, I did not test simply because I have only one remaining cd   ;-)